# jQuery: Randomly positioned divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

I'm looking to randomly position a whole load of divs (that will eventually contain images) sporadically around the page, contained within a 100%. The thing is I don't want the divs to overlap, and also all the divs will be different sizes dependant on the image.
The method I currently have:
(jsfiddle here too http://jsfiddle.net/2z4rK/ )

```
        function randomFromTo(from, to){
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
        }

        function moveRandom() {
            var cPos = $('#block-container').offset();
            var cHeight = $('#block-container').height();
            var cWidth = $('#block-container').width();

            var pad = parseInt($('#block-container').css('padding-top').replace('px', ''));

            var bHeight = $('.block').height();
            var bWidth = $('.block').width();

            maxY = cPos.top + cHeight - bHeight - pad;
            maxX = cPos.left + cWidth - bWidth - pad;

            minY = cPos.top + pad;
            minX = cPos.left + pad;



      $('.block').each(function() {

              newY = randomFromTo(minY, maxY);
              newX = randomFromTo(minX, maxX);

        $(this).animate({
                  top: newY,
                  left: newX
                  }, 500, function() {
              });
      });
        }

moveRandom();
```

This is OK, but the divs overlap, and it seems they all have to be the same size. The divs will be added dynamically by the client so I need to make it completely self sufficient which is where I think this current method fails. Is there any way to randomly position divs?
A good example of what I'm trying to achieve: http://www.jormamueller.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to write the code for you, just give you an outline:

- Create coordinates for the top left corner and bottom right corner of each rectangle (store them either in an array or object), and add them to an array of coordinates.
- On each generation of a new rectangle, check if either of its four corner's coordinates is larger than the top left corner of any of the other rectangles *and* has is smaller than the bottom right corner of the other rectangles (so check if any corners lie within any other rectangles).
- If not, generate new random coordinates for the rectangle.

You can comment if I'm not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

The site you have linked is using following technique:

- There is a grid container `div` which has the `width` of browser window and also has `relative position`.
- For each image, there's a container `div` with `absolute position`. Each `div` has `full width` and a `random left` position. `top` property of each `div` is sum of all former div heights.

---

If I was you, I would create a grid like a table with empty cells by using `div` tags and then I would put images randomly in those cells.

This can be achieved by putting all image sources and details in an array and putting all cell id's in another array; then you can shuffle both arrays and assign one image to a random cell.